# what is a vbNullChar equivalent in c#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

What is a equivalent of Visual basic 'vbNullChar" in c# ?

i want to replicate this VB statement in C#

```
Dim sVersion As String
sVersion = New String(vbNullChar, 255)
```

Comment: http://www.pressthered.com/working_with_null_characters_in_c_net/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I suspect you want:

```
string sVersion = new string('\0', 255);
```

(This seems like an odd thing to want to do though. I would try taking a step back and seeing whether there isn't a more appropriate approach to the bigger problem.)

Comment: Actual I am converting one Vb.net Application to C#.net where i found this statement that i have to write as it is ..

Comment: Agree that you should look at what you are trying to acheive rather than just converting the code - otherwise you might as well generate the C# from the IL code.

Answer (score 4):

Jon Skeet is correct...

Also you can achieve this thing by below method...

1st Way

```
char vbNullChar = Convert.ToChar(0);//C# Equivalent to vbNullChar
string sVersion = new string(vbNullChar, 255);
```

2nd Way

```
char vbNullChar = Convert.ToChar(0x0);//C# Equivalent to vbNullChar
string sVersion = new string(vbNullChar, 255);
```

Comment: You don't need `Convert.ToChar` - just `char vbNullChar = (char) 0;` will work fine, or `char vbNullChar = '\0';`