# ControlChars class in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net-to-c#

Does anyone know what is equivalent to `ControlChars.NullChar` class in C#?

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to achieve rather than the class you'd use in VB? (I suspect that the idiomatic way of achieving your goal may be entirely different in C#.)

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/026fdc49-735d-4f4f-bd63-65171981e902/anything-like-vbs-controlchars-class-in-c?forum=netfxbcl

Comment: There is very little to it, just plain const declarations.  Consider simply [copy-pasting it](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#Microsoft.VisualBasic/Microsoft/VisualBasic/ControlChars.cs,e143af56ec2014f7)

Comment: With the edit to the question, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360914

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is a vbNullChar equivalent in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360914/what-is-a-vbnullchar-equivalent-in-c)

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know not, you could use the following class (if you do not want to reference VB assembly (Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll) - please note that not all are included):

```
public static class CSharpControlChars
{
    public static readonly string NewLine = Environment.NewLine;
    public static string CrLf => $"{Cr}{Lf}";

    public const char Cr = '\r';
    public const char Lf = '\n';
    public const char FormFeed = '\f';
    public const char Null = '\0';
    public const char BackSpace = '\b';

    public const char Tab = '\t';
    public const char VertTab = '\v';
}
```

When working with RS232 interfaces I also created following class:

```
public static class Rs232Constants
    {
        public const char Null_00 = '\x00';
        public const char Soh_01 = '\x01';
        public const char Stx_02 = '\x02';
        public const char Etx_03 = '\x03';
        public const char Eot_04 = '\x04';
        public const char Enq_05 = '\x05';
        public const char Ack_06 = '\x06';
        public const char Lf_0A = '\x0A';
        public const char Mt_09 = '\x09';
        public const char Cr_0D = '\x0D';
        public const char Dc1_11 = '\x11';
        public const char Can_18 = '\x18';
        public const char Syn_22 = '\x22';
        public const char Del_7F = '\x7F';
        public const char Space_20 = '\x20';
        public const char ESC_1B = '\x1B';
    }
```

**EDIT**

Added static to class definition - thanks for the note ckuri

Comment: While the OP *could* use those, it would be more idiomatic IMO just to use the escape sequences directly.

Comment: A very minor note: the classes should be declared as static to mark them as non-instantiable.

Comment: thanks dsdel, above CSharpControlChars has sorted out my issue

Comment: @ChiragSolanki: But you never updated your question to say what your issue was. Using a class like that is very unlikely to be as readable to other C# developers as using the built-in escape sequence. For example, if you wanted to specify a string with tabs in, I'd argue that the idiomatic C# code is to write `"a\tb\tc"` for example. If you could update your question with more context, the community can advise on idiomatic options rather than just a fairly literal translation of the VB.

Comment: @Daisy Shipton naturaly you could use the escape sequences directly. But at least, speaking for myself, when working with the RS232 constants I do not need to think about how Syn is defined again. Also the OP asked for the class in c# - not for the codes itself : )

Comment: @dsdel: For RS232, that makes sense. For the Unicode null character, I don't think it makes nearly so much sense. And yes, I know what the OP asked for - which is why I asked repeatedly what they were trying to do, in order to get *behind* the question to find the best overall solution for them instead of just providing the answer to the immediate question. There are lots of questions where taking a step back leads to a better question and answer, IMO.

Comment: @Chirag Solanki please be so kind to select my answer as solution - Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

[**It's the same class**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.controlchars?view=netframework-4.7.1). All you need to do is add a reference to  Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly.

If you're unsure of how to add a reference then see:

[How to: Add or Remove References](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)

If by any chance you're using VS on mac like me, then see the accepted answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789971/how-to-add-reference-to-assembly-in-visual-studio-mac).

---

That said it's worth noting that most if not all of the fields in the [ControlChars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.controlchars?view=netframework-4.7.1) class can be done without adding a reference to the aforementioned assembly. i.e. by using character escape sequences directly in your code.

To mention a few:

- \' – single quote
- \" – double quote
- \ – backslash
- \b – backspace
- \f – form feed
- \n – new line
- \r – carriage return

Answer (score 0):

```
 public sealed class ControlChars
    {
        public const char Back = '\b';
        public const char Cr = '\r';
        public const string CrLf = "\r\n";
        public const char FormFeed = '\f';
        public const char Lf = '\n';
        public const string NewLine = "\r\n";
        public const char NullChar = '\0';
        public const char Quote = '"';
        public const char Tab = '\t';
        public const char VerticalTab = '\v';
    }
```

to add CrLf in C# use

```
Environment.NewLine;
```